# How get the typing caret position on screen?

Tags: windows, winforms

I want to get the coordinate (x, y) on the screen of the current caret.

My goal is to find that to add a custom tooltip anywhere user is typing.

Not only on my application but in all opened windows.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You mean the vertical bar? (caret) ? - In your app or in any app?

Comment: Are you trying to do this just inside your app or anywhere the caret is on the screen regardless of app?

Comment: [Control.MousePosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @adv12 I'm not talking about Mouse Position :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it would be quite enough to know the active control - that's where the user currently has focus, and thus, the keyboard cursor:

```
Form.ActiveForm.ActiveControl
```

If you need to get the information *anywhere*, not just in your application, you need to drop down to native P/Invokes:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetGUIThreadInfo(uint idThread, ref GUITHREADINFO lpgui);

public struct GUITHREADINFO
{
  public int cbSize;
  public int flags;
  public IntPtr hwndActive;
  public IntPtr hwndFocus;
  public IntPtr hwndCapture;
  public IntPtr hwndMenuOwner;
  public IntPtr hwndMoveSize;
  public IntPtr hwndCaret;
  public System.Drawing.Rectangle rcCaret;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, ref Point lpPoint);

public void Main()
{
  GUITHREADINFO gti = default(GUITHREADINFO);
  gti.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(GUITHREADINFO));

  if (!GetGUIThreadInfo(0, ref gti)) return;

  Console.WriteLine(gti.rcCaret); // The position of the caret in the parent, 
                                  // if the active control is a text box or similar

  var point = gti.rcCaret.Location;
  if (!ClientToScreen(gti.hwndCaret, ref point)) return;

  Console.WriteLine(point); // The position of the caret in screen-coördinates
}
```

Comment: i try to find active form not only on my app but on all other windows

Comment: @ChristopheDebove Ah, in that case, you want to use the native functions - get the currently active window, and the currently active control, and ask for its coördinates. It's the same idea, but note that not all applications are natively windows - there's no way to handle Java applications that way, for example. Or console applications, for that matter. That said, why are you doing this? It makes sense in your application, but if you want it system-wide, wouldn't some accessibility feature of Windows do what you need? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I know it could be dificult but with win32 api I guess we can do that at least for compatible windows form.

Comment: @ChristopheDebove Updated, this should work for most natively windows applications. Careful about screen-space coördinates on multi-monitor systems, as always. And don't forget they can be out-of-screen :) Note that includes Winforms, but not WPF (e.g. recent Visual Studios).

Answer (score -2):

Okay, you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition(v=vs.110).aspx
From PresentationFramework. This will be anothoher type of WindowsForms so you will need to rewrite everything to make it work